# 16 Nested For-Loops Speed C++/Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, for-loop, nested-loops, rcpp

I have a very computationally intensive program that I need to run for 16 nested for loops to accomplish a iterative check of all possible permutations of 16 numerical vectors each of size 26. My first attempt was in `R` (my preferred language), but was quickly redirected to `C++` via the `Rcpp` package. I can run the code locally on my PC (4-core, Intel i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz, 16GB RAM), but also have access to Azure cloud computing and can spin up a cluster of any size.

My current code looks like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericMatrix optimalIndex(NumericVector a, NumericVector b, NumericVector c, NumericVector d, NumericVector e, NumericVector f,
                           NumericVector g, NumericVector h, NumericVector i, NumericVector j, NumericVector k, NumericVector l,
                           NumericVector m, NumericVector n, NumericVector o, NumericVector p){
  NumericMatrix outp(1000000, 16);
  int index = 0;
  int minsum = 0;
  for(int c1 = 0; c1 < a.size(); c1++){
    for(int c2 = 0; c2 < b.size(); c2++){
      for(int c3 = 0; c3 < c.size(); c3++){
        for(int c4 = 0; c4 < d.size(); c4++){
          for(int c5 = 0; c5 < e.size(); c5++){
            for(int c6 = 0; c6 < f.size(); c6++){
              for(int c7 = 0; c7 < g.size(); c7++){
                for(int c8 = 0; c8 < h.size(); c8++){
                  for(int c9 = 0; c9 < i.size(); c9++){
                    for(int c10 = 0; c10 < j.size(); c10++){
                      for(int c11 = 0; c11 < k.size(); c11++){
                        for(int c12 = 0; c12 < l.size(); c12++){
                          for(int c13 = 0; c13 < m.size(); c13++){
                            for(int c14 = 0; c14 < n.size(); c14++){
                              for(int c15 = 0; c15 < o.size(); c15++){
                                for(int c16 = 0; c16 < p.size(); c16++){
                                  minsum = a(c1) + b(c2) + c(c3) + d(c4) + e(c5) + f(c6)
                                            + g(c7) + h(c8) + i(c9) + j(c10) + k(c11) + l(c12)
                                            + m(c13) + n(c14) + o(c15) + p(c16);
                                  if(minsum == 0){
                                    outp(index, 0) = c1;
                                    outp(index, 1) = c2;
                                    outp(index, 2) = c3;
                                    outp(index, 3) = c4;
                                    outp(index, 4) = c5;
                                    outp(index, 5) = c6;
                                    outp(index, 6) = c7;
                                    outp(index, 7) = c8;
                                    outp(index, 8) = c9;
                                    outp(index, 9) = c10;
                                    outp(index, 10) = c11;
                                    outp(index, 11) = c12;
                                    outp(index, 12) = c13;
                                    outp(index, 13) = c14;
                                    outp(index, 14) = c15;
                                    outp(index, 15) = c16;
                                    outp(index, 16) = c17;
                                    outp(index, 17) = c18;
                                    outp(index, 18) = c19;
                                    outp(index, 19) = c20;
                                    outp(index, 20) = c21;
                                    outp(index, 21) = c22;
                                    outp(index, 22) = c23;
                                    outp(index, 23) = c24;
                                    outp(index, 24) = c25;
                                    outp(index, 25) = c26;
                                    outp(index, 26) = c27;
                                    outp(index, 27) = c28;
                                    outp(index, 28) = c29;
                                    outp(index, 29) = c30;
                                    outp(index, 30) = c31;
                                    index++;
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(outp);
}
```

The dimension of the output of this function, `outp`, is unknown at this point, so I arbitrarily chose 1 million rows. I want to return the index of each column where the row sum matches a specified condition, ie. = 0.

Obviously, this is taking what feels like YEARS to run. I am not sure if parallelization is an option for this loop, or what other methods I can use to increase speed. Like I said, I can run in Azure with more cores and/or more memory if that will do it.

Is there a better/faster way to do this?

Comment: Nested loops to generate permutations? Have you seen [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)? That might be appropriate here.

Comment: is approximation a possibility here?

Comment: What does `a(c1)`, `b(c2)` .... correspond to? Functions? Simple ones? If not, calculate `ac1 = a(c1)` just after setting of `c1`...etc.

Comment: @cigien I am not familiar with `std::next_permutation` as it has been some time since I last coded in `C++`. Can you share how you would implement such a function?

Comment: @pete Approximation of what...?

Comment: Two questions: are you looking *only* for the cases where minsum is zero? And are any of the elements a through p negative? Because if minsum has to be zero and elements are always non-negative, there's a much, much faster algorithm to solve things

Comment: There's nothing to implement really. Take a look at the link I shared, see how it's used, and then it should be fairly clear whether that's applicable to your problem. If you run into difficulties *using* it, well, that's what SO is for :)

Comment: @Damien `a`, `b`, `c`, `etc` are the numerical vectors. `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `etc` are the vector indexes. So `a(c1)` is the first element of vector `a`. I believe with `Rcpp` brackets and parenthesis function the same way.

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez Yes, just looking for indexes where minsum is zero. Vector values range from -30 to +30.

Comment: @KylePower it will take around a 130,000 years to brute force it, and while it is parallelizable, you'd still be using up nearly all of a supercomputer for the better part of a year, but there are better algorithms we can use. Are elements of NumericVector guaranteed to be integers?

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez Yes! All elements of NumericVector are guaranteed to be signed integers.

Comment: I think I have a solution, give me a second to work on it

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez Fantastic!! I appreciate your help so much! and just to note, I am open to any coding language - no reason it has to be `R` or `C++`

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez Feel free to email me at power.kyle28@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to run this program in reasonable time as 26^16 is equal to 43,608,742,899,428,874,059,776. I think there is much faster solution to this problem using dynamic programming with states dp[SUM][letterIndex]. You can precompute how many combinations of letters are there with sum equal to SUM with letterIndex letters used. Complexity of this solution is O(26*16*MAX) where MAX is maximum value in your vectors. Of course, this is valid if numbers in vectors are integers.